# Top-align row of Grid and Plot

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts, alignment

How can the top of the `Column` on the right (built from a `Grid`) to be aligned with the top of the `Plot` on the left?

```
x = N[2 Pi/24] Range[0, 5];
data = Transpose[{x, Chop@Sin[x]}];
grf = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium];

title = Item[Text["sine data"], Alignment -> Center];
hdr = Item[Text[#], Alignment -> Center] & /@ {"x", "sin x"};
tbl = Style[
   Column[{title, Grid[Prepend[data, hdr], Alignment -> "."]}], Bold, 
   10];

Panel[Row[{grf, Spacer[50], tbl},
  Alignment -> Top, BaselinePosition -> Center], 
 Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image: How align plot and table at their tops?]

(I'm using `Panel` just the better to show the displayed output; the same problem arises without `Panel` or with using `Framed` instead.)

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap each element with `Pane[#, BaselinePosition -> Top] &`:

```
Panel[Row[
  Pane[#, BaselinePosition -> Top] & /@ {grf, Spacer[50], tbl}], 
 Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Aside from controllable size, what exactly is the difference between a Pane and a Panel?

Comment: @Alan, `Panel` has convenient labeling and background styling. You can see some of the differences using `FilterRules[Options[Pane], Except@Options[Panel]]` and `FilterRules[Options[Panel], Except@Options[Pane]]`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using GraphicsRow:

```
x = N[2 Pi/24] Range[0, 5];
data = Transpose[{x, Chop@Sin[x]}];
grf = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
   Frame -> True,
   ImageSize -> 400,
   AspectRatio -> 0.75, 
   ImagePadding -> {{80, 20}, {15, 5}}
   ];

title = Item[Style["sine data", 18, Blue], Alignment -> Center];
hdr = Item[Style[#, Bold, Blue, 10], Alignment -> Center] & /@ {"x", 
    "sin x"};
tbl = Style[
   Column[{title, Grid[Prepend[data, hdr],
      FrameStyle -> {Thin},
      Frame -> All,
      Spacings -> {2, 1.2},
      Alignment -> "."]}
    ],
   10, FontFamily -> "Consolas"
   ];

GraphicsRow[{grf, tbl},
 Alignment -> Top,
 Spacings -> Scaled[-0.25],
 Background -> {LightBlue, LightBlue},
 ImageSize -> 800,
 AspectRatio -> 0.4
 ]
```

[image]

Minor edit: using Negative Scaling to resize the columns of a `GraphicsRow` so that the plot would occupy more space and look better still. I took certain liberties with formatting, that I hope you will forgive.